# Possible bug with new ga:clientId GA API field

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, clientid

I'm trying out a new default clientID dimension in Google Analytic Reporting API.

I keep getting duplicate clientIDs and total event action count for the same day when the RowCount is > 10000. I can easily get rid of unwatned rows but I wonder why it happens.
I retrieve data for one day and filter on Event Action. I get the sampled data.
What's more the count of total events retrieved by Reporting API is larger than the one retrived by User Activity API for the same clientID. The former is sampled while the latter is not so the count should actually be bigger in the second case.

My queries look like this:

**Reporting API**

```
query = {
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': '',
          'dateRanges': [{'startDate':'2019-08-21', 'endDate': '2019-08-21'}],
          'metrics': [
                {'expression': 'ga:totalEvents'} ],
          'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:clientID'}],
          'dimensionFilterClauses': [

              {     'operator': 'OR',
          'filters': [


               {
                  'dimensionName': 'ga:eventAction',
                  'not': False,
                  'expressions':[
                    ''
                  ],
                  'caseSensitive': False
              },





          ],
                                     }
      ],
          'segments': [],
           'samplingLevel':'LARGE',
            'pageSize':'10000',

      }
        ]
}
```

**User API**

```
queryUser = {
    "viewId": "",
    "user": {
        "type": "CLIENT_ID",
        "userId": ""
    },
    "dateRange": {
        "startDate": "2019-08-21",
        "endDate": "2019-08-21",
    }
}
```

It's still an undocumented feature so maybe that's why I'm getting these errors. Or could there be more fixable reasons?